# Ajax response text is always 1

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending two variables to my php page for calculation then echoing the end result back. My response text always equals one.

The Javascript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.open("GET","calc.php?w1="+ftest+"&w2="+ltest,true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xhttp.readyState==4)   
     {   
         var dog = xhttp.responseText;
         alert(dog); 
     }   
    };
   xhttp.send(null);
  }
```

The php:

I set the end var to a random number here just to test if my math was causing the problem.

```
$startdate = $_GET['w1'];
$endDate = $_GET['w2'];
$workingdays = 239;
echo $workingDays;
```

Comment: Check variable in this line `$workingdays = 239;` that should equal to `echo $workingDays;`

Answer (score 2):

Set `$workingDays` directly to `10` ( random number ).  If it is not 10, then you are clearly not seeing the result of that echo statement.

`1` is often used as the output to native PHP functions such as `isset`

Answer (score 2):

You're case is wrong.

```
$workingdays = 239;
echo $workingDays;
```

Make it workingDays (with capital D) in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `isset()` for receiving data and you are using variable `$workingdays` for declaration and for echo `$workingDays`, take care of these things. I hope this will work for you.

```
$startdate = '';
$endDate ='';
if(isset($_GET['w1']))
{
    $startdate = $_GET['w1'];
}
if(isset($_GET['w2']))
{
   $endDate = $_GET['w2'];
}

$workingdays = 239;
echo $workingdays;
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this variable in your ajax code just to make a test if in the server side is receiving the data you sent using get method.

```
var ftest = 1;
var ltest = 2;
```

I assumed that your ajax code is inside the a function let say `myfunction` and you have a link like this `<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">link</a>`

Here is the full implementation of the code assuming that your filename is `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ajax</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">link</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunction () {
        var ftest = 1;
        var ltest = 2;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET","calc.php?w1="+ftest+"&w2="+ltest,true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(xhttp.readyState==4) {
            var dog = xhttp.responseText;
            alert(dog);
          }
        };
        xhttp.send(null);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and Calc.php

```
<?php
  $startdate   = $_GET['w1'];
  $endDate     = $_GET['w2'];
  $workingdays = 239;
  $result = $startdate + $endDate;
  echo "$result";
?>
```

In this example you alert will equal to **3** it be same in your code

Hope this will help